# Admin link/url to Media Library in Folder Path

Tags: kentico, administration, media-library

Is it possible to generate a direct admin link to the Media Library App on a specific Gallery and Folder Path?

[image]

In the example above, I'd like to have a link to Media Library Gallery, with the Test folder selected.

I've tried setting the objectid (library id) as such http://localhost:51872/Admin/CMSAdministration.aspx?objectid=3#436564ee-89e9-4719-939a-0d7b57ece744 but doesn't seem to work.

I'm on a latest hotfix v8 site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible, because Kentico UI has been built on WebForms and it uses UpdatePanels for ajax POST calls and all values related to the current path are held in hidden inputs. In other words you can only update basic page UI via Post requests with specific values in inputs.

Comment: yah, I guess that might be the case. But as it's possible to so with Nodes in the Pages App, I wondered if there was some "hidden" querystrings that could help on this one.